# Accessing React.DOM.input has been deprecated will be removed in v16.0+?

Tags: reactjs

A warning occured on my new React project

`Accessing factories like React.DOM.input has been deprecated and will be removed in v16.0+. Use the react-dom-factories package instead.  Version 1.0 provides a drop-in replacement. For more info, see.......`

Anyone encountering same problem ? How to solve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DOM.input` is a *factory*, a function which returns a React Element (something that can be rendered by React). Either you're using this directly in your code, for example:

```
class MyInput extends Component {
    render() {
        return DOM.input(props, children);
    }
}
```

or some library that you're using is doing so.

Instead of using `DOM` from the React package, you should install a separate package, [react-dom-factories](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom-factories), and use `DOM` from there.

Alternatively, you can enable JSX and use `<input>` instead.